# Как примапить локальную папку в docker-machine?

Tags: docker

Я хочу примапить папку проекта в хост докер-машины.

В качестве провайдера я использую virtualbox.

я поставил **virtualbox 5**
Поставил **docker-machine**
Создал командой вм dev

```
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default
```

И я теперь не могу понять как мне прокинуть в эту вм папку проекта.
Для примера в контейнерах мы делаем `-v /project:/projectincontainer` тут я нашел только json конфиг в своей домашней директории, что нужно дописать в него или какие ключи указать в командной строке при запуске машины?

Работаю на Ubuntu 14.04

Пример конфига

```
{
    "ConfigVersion": 3,
    "Driver": {
        "IPAddress": "192.168.99.100",
        "MachineName": "default",
        "SSHUser": "docker",
        "SSHPort": 54921,
        "SSHKeyPath": "/home/zhag/.docker/machine/machines/default/id_rsa",
        "StorePath": "/home/zhag/.docker/machine",
        "SwarmMaster": false,
        "SwarmHost": "tcp://0.0.0.0:3376",
        "SwarmDiscovery": "",
        "VBoxManager": {},
        "CPU": 1,
        "Memory": 1024,
        "DiskSize": 20000,
        "Boot2DockerURL": "",
        "Boot2DockerImportVM": "",
        "HostDNSResolver": false,
        "HostOnlyCIDR": "192.168.99.1/24",
        "HostOnlyNicType": "82540EM",
        "HostOnlyPromiscMode": "deny",
        "NoShare": false,
        "DNSProxy": false,
        "NoVTXCheck": false
    },
    "DriverName": "virtualbox",
    "HostOptions": {
        "Driver": "",
        "Memory": 0,
        "Disk": 0,
        "EngineOptions": {
            "ArbitraryFlags": [],
            "Dns": null,
            "GraphDir": "",
            "Env": [],
            "Ipv6": false,
            "InsecureRegistry": [],
            "Labels": [],
            "LogLevel": "",
            "StorageDriver": "",
            "SelinuxEnabled": false,
            "TlsVerify": true,
            "RegistryMirror": [],
            "InstallURL": "https://get.docker.com"
        },
        "SwarmOptions": {
            "IsSwarm": false,
            "Address": "",
            "Discovery": "",
            "Master": false,
            "Host": "tcp://0.0.0.0:3376",
            "Image": "swarm:latest",
            "Strategy": "spread",
            "Heartbeat": 0,
            "Overcommit": 0,
            "ArbitraryFlags": [],
            "Env": null
        },
        "AuthOptions": {
            "CertDir": "/home/zhag/.docker/machine/certs",
            "CaCertPath": "/home/zhag/.docker/machine/certs/ca.pem",
            "CaPrivateKeyPath": "/home/zhag/.docker/machine/certs/ca-key.pem",
            "CaCertRemotePath": "",
            "ServerCertPath": "/home/zhag/.docker/machine/machines/default/server.pem",
            "ServerKeyPath": "/home/zhag/.docker/machine/machines/default/server-key.pem",
            "ClientKeyPath": "/home/zhag/.docker/machine/certs/key.pem",
            "ServerCertRemotePath": "",
            "ServerKeyRemotePath": "",
            "ClientCertPath": "/home/zhag/.docker/machine/certs/cert.pem",
            "ServerCertSANs": [],
            "StorePath": "/home/zhag/.docker/machine/machines/default"
        }
    },
    "Name": "default"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вы запустили `docker-machine` нужно указать `docker` запускаться не локально, а на удаленной машине.

```
$eval "$(docker-machine env default)"
```

Дальше работаем как с обычным докером.

```
docker run -v /path/my/host/project:/path/in/container -ti ubuntu /bin/bash
```